# Building string based on combination of checked checkboxes

Tags: ms-access, vba

On a form I have 3 checkboxes - `chk1`, `chk2`, & `chk3`.

The where clause of an SQL statement will be built, based on what combination of boxes are ticked.

So, if only `chk1` is checked I need my string to be :-

```
where x=1
```

But if `chk1` and `chk2` are checked, I need my string to be :-

```
where x=1 or x=2
```

What is the best approach to build the string? I've tried nested ifs, but it seems very messy, and I'm sure there must be a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way I build SQL clauses is the following way:

```
Dim strWhere As String
strWhere = "WHERE 1=1" 'Always true
If chk1 Then
    strWhere = strWhere & " OR x=1"
End If
If chk2 Then
    strWhere = strWhere & " OR x=2"
End If
If chk3 Then
    strWhere = strWhere & " OR x=3"
End If
strWhere = Replace(strWhere, "1=1 OR ", "") 'Remove always true if something has been set
```

This way, you can easily extend the where clause by adding extra criteria.

In this case, though, since you're only comparing a single value, I'd use the following:

```
Dim strWhere As String
strWhere = "WHERE x IN (Null" 'In(Null) is valid, but will return Null = false if null and false if any other value
If chk1 Then
    strWhere = strWhere & ",1"
End If
If chk2 Then
    strWhere = strWhere & ",2"
End If
If chk3 Then
    strWhere = strWhere & ",3"
End If
strWhere = strWhere & ")"
```

These will behave differently when none are checked. The first approach will return everything in that case, the second none.

Comment: Thanks again for you help today :-)